How to use the `=short-text` method in conjunction with a key-value list
The usrguide  section 2.9 outtlines the =short text method for picking up optional arguments as either keys or text, such as the short toc title in commands like caption etc. I need some code to grab these arguments and put them in either booleans or macros. There is a case that does not seem to be covered by the method provided, how to capture both the short title text and a set of keys, as for example:
\mycaption[=short title{,key1,key2=value etc}]{A very long title}

This type of to work both with and without a star. With a star I will provide a key to save or not save the short title in the toc. I would appreciate some help here. In the code below, the red result is the short title. It reacts correctly (never had any doubt!), except in the combined case of having a short title and some option key-list.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\savetitle#1{
\def\savedtitle{{\bfseries #1}}
}
\def\saveshorttitlekeyval#1{
 \def\savedshorttitleaux##1=##2;{{\color{red}##2}}
  \def\savedshorttitle{
    \savedshorttitleaux#1;
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand
\mycaption{s ={short-mytext} +O{#3} +m }
{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{
  {hasstar ~} \saveshorttitlekeyval{#2} 
  }{nostar~   \saveshorttitlekeyval{#2}}
  
  \savetitle{#3}
 }
 \ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
1. \mycaption[=some short title]{long title}\savedtitle  \savedshorttitle

2. \mycaption[some short title]{long title}\savedtitle  \savedshorttitle

3. \mycaption[={size=10pt,color=blue}]{long title}\savedtitle \savedshorttitle

4. \mycaption{Only my caption}\savedtitle       \savedshorttitle             

5. \mycaption*{Starred my caption}\savedtitle   \savedshorttitle            % 

6. \mycaption*{Starred short title and long title} \savedtitle \savedshorttitle

\end{document}


'Sheep and goats' - either you have a non-keyval short value, or a full set of keyvals where you give the short title explicitly with a key - I'm guessing this does not come across in the examples?

@JosephWright  I need both sheep for the kids and goats to make halloumi cheese! It sort of came through in the examples in the guide, but I was hoping if someone can add some extra parsing.

you have the commas inside the {} which is odd I can't guess how you intend that to be parsed, but the intended use here is \mycaption[toc=short title, key2=value etc}]{A very long title} with \caption[short title]{...] being equivalent to \caption[toc=short title]{...]

The = is just part of the decaration syntax, not something to use in the document use. see texdoc usrguide so your examples 1 and 3 look like syntax errors.

@DavidCarlisle  the intention of the comma was to end up with short-text=somevalue,key1,key2,key3=blue etc, i.e to turn the whole capture into a single key-list. I am sure you can come up with a better method.

why not simply document to the user that that is the input? why do you need a different input to parse to that?

@DavidCarlisle  because I think is easier for the user. If it cannot be done then I would rather provide an extra key short and avoid this style.

No honestly it's much much harder, this user for example would not be able to guess what the syntax was intended to do it's just so alien to the rest of latex.

I would rather provide an extra key short that is exactly what this system does you define a key say short and for all internal processing treat it as a normal keyval ist,. but (for legacy compatiblity) if the option has no key=value then the whole option is read as short=the value

you could treat an unknown key as a value to pass to short, but you can't then pick up if a user actually tries to use an unknown key. (this doesn't have anything to do with the = syntax.)

The = is just part of the declaration, not the user syntax. The intention is that the command definition always sees a keyval list whether or not the user explicitly uses keyval.
Here if no key is used short= is assumed.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn{abc}{
  short .tl_set:N =\savedshorttitle,
  key1 .tl_set:N =\keyone,
  size .tl_set:N =\keysize,
  color .tl_set:N =\keycolor
  }
\NewDocumentCommand
\mycaption{s ={short} O{#3}  +m }
{%
  \def\savedtitle{#3}
  \keys_set:nn{abc}{#2}
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
  {hasstar ~ }
  {nostar~}
  }
 \ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

1. \mycaption[some short title]{long title}\savedtitle,  \savedshorttitle

2. \mycaption[size=10pt,color=blue]{long title}\savedtitle, \savedshorttitle

3. \mycaption[short=something,size=10pt,color=blue]{long title}\savedtitle, \savedshorttitle

4. \mycaption{Only my caption}\savedtitle,      \savedshorttitle             

5. \mycaption*{Starred my caption}\savedtitle   \savedshorttitle            % 

6. \mycaption*{Starred short title and long title} \savedtitle, \savedshorttitle

\end{document}


This is by-design. The ltcmd syntax is there to allow existing usage
\section[A short title]{A much longer title that we don't always want}

while if you are adding keys then this also covers the sort title
\section[short-title = A short title, label = mysec, include-in-toc = true]
  {A much longer title that we don't always want}

As such the expectation is that users will either have unmodified input that does not know about keys, or updated input that does: not some halfway situation.
